# Function call inside a loop in C

Tags: c

```
int random(){//function for random number generation
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
int rand = rand()%468;
return rand;
}
```

I want to put this function in a loop so it assigns a random number to a variable during each iteration of the loop, so i figured i would try this:

```
for(x=0;x<n;x++){
y=random();
printf("%d\n",y);
}
```

However this doesn't work as i expected, y just gets the number from the first iteration and repeats it, can someone explain how i can force the function to recall so it will set a new value to y?

Comment: Call `srand` *once* at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not call `srand()` everytime before calling `rand()`.

The way you are calling `srand()` always passes the same value as the seed, because the difference in *seconds* between each call is `0`, since it's a lot smaller than `1s`.

Since you always call `srand()` with the same seed and right before `rand()`, **you will get always the same value** from `rand()`.

Just call `srand()` once at the start of the program, so in every run there will be different random numbers generated.

Comment: i didn't even consider that, thank you

Comment: @BlazeBlue you should accept his answer then. :)

Comment: @ G. Samaras will do..but there's a minimum time that needs to pass apparently